# Compare the system with linearized system and determine if it contradicts Hartman Grobman Theorem

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Determine the nature of the critical point at the origin for the following system for all possible values of a:

$\dot{x}=-y+ax(x^2+y^2)$ 
$\dot{y}=x+ay(x^2+y^2)$.

Compare with the behavior of the linearized system. Does this contradict with Hartman-Grobman Theorem?

Which invariant manifolds exist at the origin? Describe the phase portrait of this system.

So here's my attempt at solving this problem:
I found the Jacobian which is $Df = \begin{pmatrix} 3ax^2+ay^2 & -1+2axy \\ 1+2axy & ax^2+3ay^2\end{pmatrix}$.

So $Df(0,0)=\begin{pmatrix} 0 & -1 \\ 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$. Since the trace is $0$ and determinant is $1$ so it is a center with eigenvalues of $i$ and $-i$. Therefore, its stable but not asymptotically stable. So is this the linearized version? Since real part of eigenvalue is $0$, so a center subspace exists. But does a center manifold also exists then? Also, does different values of $a$ matter since the only equilibrium point is the origin $(0,0)$?

I know according to Hartman-Grobman theorem, in neighborhood of origin, behavior of the system is topologically homeomorphic to linearized system if the matrix $Df(0,0)$ has no eigenvalue with zero part. So it doesn't apply here right? And what is the center manifold in this case?

Answer (score 1):

You can compute the radius dynamic as
$$
r\dot r=x\dot x+y\dot y=ar^4
$$
which can be explicitly solved. This then shows that for $a<0$ the origin is asymptotically stable, for $a>0$ it is unstable with trajectories going to infinity in finite time.

Comment: That makes sense but then $Df(0,0)$ gives eigenvalues of $0+i$ and $0-i$ so would that not make it center and therefore just stable?

Comment: No, as you cited in the question, in the case where the real parts are zero, the local behavior is determined by the higher order terms in the equation, the linearization is not sufficient to decide stability.